# list of commands for nsclient++

Tags: nagios, nsclient++, centreon

After executing the following command  get the correct result

```
./check_nrpe -H @IP -p 5666 -c alias_mem
OK: committed = 6.083GB, physical = 1.608GB|'committed'=6.08327GB;12.7978;14.39752;0;15.99725....
```

The issue is that I haven't found any documentation that lists all the possible commands.. I've tried alias_cpu, alias_disk and it works but I'd like to find all the possible commands ...

Comment: https://docs.nsclient.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see some commands which are already created in nsclient.ini in the form of alias.

You could look at the help of each command to specify which options you want to see in your supervision.

Finally, you can create your own script and add it in the nsclient.ini